# Get the line number in the source document instead of transformed document using XPath and Saxon in Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, saxon

Are there any way to use Saxon in Java that is able to return the line number of the matched element in the source document?
For example, I have the following XML

```
<property name="random name" value="
        -firstSentence=false
        -secondSentence=true
        -thirdSentence=true" />
```

I am interested in the 3rd line in the original document. And I used the following XPath:

```
/property[matches(@value, '^.*secondSentence=true.*$')]
```

And call getLineNumber in XdmNode in Saxon, it return to me line number 2
I found out that the orginal formatting of the XML document is gone when parsing into an XdmNode using DocumentBuilder

It returned the following formatted xml and ran XPath on it

```
<property name="random name"
      value="                          -firstSentence=false                          -secondSentence=true                         -thirdSentence=true"/>
```

In which the value data has been clamped into a single line and that's the line where the XPath is run on and returned line number

I was wondering if is there any possible way for Saxon to be able to not auto format the XML document and process the XPath rule on it so that the line number returned from the XdmNode reflect that exact line in the original document?

Or if you know any XML parsing library / XPath that can do this as well?

Answer (score 0):

When you switch line numbering on in Saxon, it retains the line numbers reported by the XML parser. In the case of a SAX parser, the line number reported for each SAX event represents the position in the source file of the end of the construct giving arise to that event. Attributes are reported as part of a startElement() event, so the best we can do is to report the position of the ">" character appearing at the end of the start tag.

This actually has nothing to do with Attribute Value Normalization, which is a process applied to attribute values by the XML parser, causing newline and tab characters to be replaced by spaces. (The only thing the two problems have in common is that in both cases the XML parser is following the rules, and Saxon has no way of telling it to do otherwise).

If you really want to solve this problem you'll probably have to do something similar to what oXygen (I beleive) does: it takes the line and column number reported by Saxon for the end of the start tag, and then reads back from there in the source file to find where the relevant attribute is, so that it can "red-flag" the offending attribute by showing it underlined.

Alternatively, it's possible that (meaning, it might be worth investigating whether) finer-grained location information is available from a Stax parser like Woodstox or Aalto, where each attribute is notified as a separate event. If that's the case, then although Saxon isn't able to record attribute-level location information, you could pass it through in some other way, for example by using a custom NodeFactory with the linked tree model to put the information in a subclass of the standard ElementImpl representation of elements.